# Regex Match Sentence Except When it Contains a Word

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex that our mail filter can use to analyse the message headers of an email and look for a specific header and act upon it depending on whether a word is in that header...

So:

I want to match:

```
X-FEAS-ANTIVIRUS: FortiSandbox:
```

except when it is

```
X-FEAS-ANTIVIRUS: FortiSandbox:  uri
```

I've tried:

```
/(?:X\-FEAS\-ANTIVIRUS\:\ FortiSandbox\:\ \ (?:[^uri]*))/
```

But it didn't work, so tried:

```
/(?:[^X\-FEAS\-ANTIVIRUS\:\ FortiSandbox\:\ \ uri]*)(?:X\-FEAS\-ANTIVIRUS\:\ FortiSandbox\:)/
```

And neither did that.

I need to be specific about the whole "X-FEAS-ANTIVIRUS: FortiSandbox:" header so that there's no chance that the action is taken in error if it matched a different header by accident that contained "uri".

Thank you!

Comment: Try `X-FEAS-ANTIVIRUS: FortiSandbox:(?! *uri)`

Comment: Why not match to end of line? `/^X-FEAS-ANTIVIRUS: FortiSandbox:$/`

Comment: Will try thanks
Don't want to match just to end of line as I want URI's to be handled differently to malware and the phrase "uri" is the only constant value, the rest can be anything (those are the ones I want to catch). So match whole phrase except when includes "uri" is the best way I could think of.